# Unit testing of DAO

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dao, sample

It is my first time to make a Unit testing so i'm trying to find references to how to make a Unit testing of a DAO. Can you guys make a simple example of the `setUpBeforeClass`, `setUp` and `how to test a method that inserting new data in database using model for this`. Just a simple example using easy mock. Thank you for your consideration

Comment: For what programming language? Using what unit testing framework?

Comment: I'm not sure that you're looking for. A simple google search throws up  lots of questions and answers on SO and lots of document with strategies for doing this.

Comment: @zerkms i'm using java, and mockito if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @PreetSangha I already tried google but what i've search isn't filling the gap to my lack of knowledge, that's why i tried to ask here for a sample so i can follow the steps from it

Comment: A DAO is an integration class, so there's little to no value to test it using mocks (are you going to mock a SQL resultset?). After all a DAO has only the logic to retrieve the data from the external system.

Comment: @Augusto what do you suggest bro? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @newbie Run it as an integration test, against a real database without mocking anything. As how to set the database, there are many strategies. You can use something like dbunit to insert data required by the tests, and assert the status of the database once the test has run. The website from dbunit has quite a few examples and "how to" guides.

Comment: @Augusto can you give some links. I really don't know where to start. I'm stuck to this for a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The idea of using mock objects to perform your unit testing strikes me as peculiar as all you are doing is testing your mock objects instead of your real ones. If you think you need to use mock objects to emulate database access then your entire architecture is wrong. I personally build all my software using the 3-Tier Architecture where I can have as many objects as I like in the Business layer, but only 1 object in the Data Access layer. Thus if I wanted to exchange real database access with dummy database access where would I make the change? All 200+ objects in my Business layer, or just the 1 object in the Data Access layer? Why should I then implement a mechanism to change every object within my application when all I really need to do is change one?
>
> Controllers are meant to be integration tested, not unit tested. But the testing pyramid prescribes that the unit level is where the focus should be, so people are sucked into that by default.
>
> Assertions should never fail under any circumstance. 
>   If they fail in your tests, it indicates a logical error. 
>   Basically, if your function is doing "assert( 0 )" instead of returning an error code, then the function should be re-written.
>
> Can you make massive changes to a class definition — even throw out the whole thing and replace it with a completely different implementation — without impacting any of the code that uses that class's objects?
>
> As has unfortunately happened with a variety of patterns that originate from rigid languages like Java, Dependency Injection has spread and been advocated as a cross-language best practice on trumped up benefits of flexibility and malleability.

**References**

- [Dependency Injection is Evil - Tony Marston](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dependency-injection-is-evil.html)
- [Test Induced Design Damage - David Heinemeier Hansson](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html)
- [TDDing Getters and Setters Considered Harmful](http://blog.james-carr.org/2010/02/10/tdding-getters-and-setters-considered-harmful/)
- [Why Getter and Setter Methods are Evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html?page=2)
- [Dependency injection is not a virtue in Ruby (DHH)](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2012/dependency-injection-is-not-a-virtue.html)
- [TDD the RITE Way – JavaScript Scene – Medium](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/tdd-the-rite-way-53c9b46f45e3)
- [5 Common Misconceptions About TDD & Unit Tests – JavaScript Scene – Medium](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/5-common-misconceptions-about-tdd-unit-tests-863d5beb3ce9)
- [Ned Batchelder: tl;dw: Stop mocking, start testing](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/tldw_stop_mocking_start_testing.html)
- [ACCU :: Mocks are Bad, Layers are Bad](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2108)
- [Google Testing Blog: Testing on the Toilet: Don’t Overuse Mocks](https://testing.googleblog.com/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html)