# One DAO class for access a database in SQL server, MySQL and MongoDB

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, mongodb

Is there a way to create one DAO class like EmployeeDAO and this class should be able to work with `SQL Server`, `MySql` and `MongoDB`. It should somehow change and work with `MySqlConnection/SqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand/SqlCommand`. Right now, I have to create three classses for each database. Are there any interfaces that I can use? I could not find any. Thank you.

```
public abstract class DaoFactory
{
  public static DaoFactory GetInstance(DaoConnection daoConnection)
    {
        DaoFactory instance = null;

        switch (daoConnection)
        {
                case DaoConnection.Default:
                case DaoConnection.MySQL:
            {
                instance = new MySqlConnectionFactory(MySqlServer, MySqlPort, MySqlUser, MySqlPassword);
                break;
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

 protected string ConnectionString { get; set; }

 public abstract DbConnection GetConnection();

}

public class MySqlConnectionFactory : DaoFactory
{
    public MySqlConnectionFactory(string server, string port, string user, string password) : base(server, port, user, password)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = string.Format("Server={0}; Port={1} Uid={2}; Pwd={3}; pooling=true", server, port, user, password);
    }

    public override DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
    }
}


public class EmployeeDao : IEmployeeDao
{
    private const string InsertEmployee = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES (@name,@age)";

    private DaoFactory daoFactory;

    EmployeeDao(DaoFactory daoFactory)
    {
        this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
    }

    public void Insert(Employee employee)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection =  (MySqlConnection) this.daoFactory.GetConnection();

        using (connection)
        {
            var commannd = new MySqlCommand(InsertEmployee, connection);
            commannd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably just keep using 3 separate classes. This is better design and much easier to maintain. What is your reason for not wanting to continue using 3 classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing of DAO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584713/unit-testing-of-dao)

Answer (score 1):

Still a valid question in 2018. I believe the answer is Microsoft Orleans, which has incredibly **serious design implications** (see [Actor Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model)), but abstracts the database entirely.
Recommend looking into this for a full boilerplate:  https://github.com/Maarten88/rrod

From there you can use:

- https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Runtime-Implementation-Details/Relational-Storage.html
- and/or https://github.com/OrleansContrib/Orleans.Providers.MongoDB

The design pattern is worthy of an entire topic on it's own: 
https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Introduction.html

It's a very hefty implementation, but I believe it's the correct approach to this problem.
Additionally, using the RROD boilerplate as a reference should secure the application for Horizontal Scaling both at the App & DB levels (whether that be 
 NoSql or ACID).